Where can I find the English translation of Viramitrodaya?
Where can I find the English translation of Viramitrodaya, a treatise (Nivandha) on the Hindu inheritance law? Viramitrodaya was popular in the Varanasi region. It was based on Dharmasastras.

Which Viramitrodaya - the commentary or the digest ?

You can find the entire collection of Hindu Law books translated into English in one volume, including Viramitrodaya (Part II, Page 275; Page Number 760 if you count from Page 1 of Part I).
A Complete Collection of Hindu Law Books on Inheritance translated into English with an Introduction by S.S.Setlur, published from Madras, 1911
